# Does obscuring mist get burned away by non-magical fire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

In Pathfinder, obscuring mist can be burned away by magical fire in the path that it takes, I think. The description doesn't say anything about non-magical fire, such as torches if you're inside, or a furnace. So does non-magical fire have any effect on magical mist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It specifies three spells and other similar fire spells that can burn away the mist, but non-magical flame isn't mentioned. Since magical *and* non-magical winds are mentioned, the lack of mention of non-magical flames is conspicuous and strongly implies that the flame must be magical.

From a common-sense perspective this makes sense. It wouldn't be much of an obscuring mist if something as easy as waving a torch around could disperse it, right?

Comment: Per http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/obscuring-mist it does specifically say "A fireball, flame strike, or similar spell burns away the fog in the explosive or fiery spell's area" so I don't think it requires inference that other magical flames do...

Comment: @mxyzplk Right you are! I somehow forgot that between reading and posting.

Answer (score 1):

From what is found in the Core book *Obscuring Mist*(**pg.317 Core**), any spell that deals fire damage can remove the effects of *Obscuring Mist*. This can be determined by the spells referenced, *Fireball* and *Firewall* are straight fire damage, and the reason it is any spell is that *Flame Strike* is half holy damage and half fire(**pg.283 Core**).

Now the area of the cloud affected is different, Wall of Fire only neutralizes the spell in the area it resides, so it can be said that Fireball and Flamestrike also only effect the squares they target, but that is not taken into account as the area each covers is large enough to remove the whole mist.

That being said I would have to agree with SevenSidedDie, that only magical flame can affect it.